# How to return value the stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteDealer 
(**In dealerCode Varchar(100),In userId VARCHAR(100**))
BEGIN
  `UPDATE tbl_dealer SET status='INACTIVE' where dealerCode=dealerCode';
  `UPDATE tbl_dealer_contact SET status='INACTIVE' where dealerCode=dealerCode';
  'UPDATE tbl_login set status='INACTIVE' where userId=userId';


END;
```

**This is my procedure how to return the boolean** 
Anyone give me quick answer

Comment: store procedure not return value

Answer (score 0):

You can use OUT parameters in procedures to return a value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteDealer 
(In dealerCode Varchar(100),In userId VARCHAR(100), OUT result INT)
BEGIN
  `UPDATE tbl_dealer SET status='INACTIVE' where dealerCode=dealerCode';
  `UPDATE tbl_dealer_contact SET status='INACTIVE' where dealerCode=dealerCode';
  'UPDATE tbl_login set status='INACTIVE' where userId=(select userId from tbl_dealer_contact where dealerCode=dealerCode)';

   set result = 1; // your value
END;
```

While calling,

```
call deleteDealer('dealerCode', 'userId', @result);
```

the result can be viewed from

```
select @result;
```

Please try this options.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteDealer 
(**In dealerCode Varchar(100),
In userId VARCHAR(100**))
BEGIN
  `UPDATE tbl_dealer SET status='INACTIVE' where dealerCode=dealerCode';
  `UPDATE tbl_dealer_contact SET status='INACTIVE' where dealerCode=dealerCode';
  'UPDATE tbl_login set status='INACTIVE' where userId=userId';


SELECT 1;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteDealer 
(**In dealerCode Varchar(100),In userId VARCHAR(100**))
BEGIN
  `UPDATE tbl_dealer SET status='INACTIVE' where dealerCode=dealerCode';
  `UPDATE tbl_dealer_contact SET status='INACTIVE' where dealerCode=dealerCode';
  'UPDATE tbl_login set status='INACTIVE' where userId=userId';

  select 1;


END;
```

Answer (score 0):

public boolean deleteDealer(DealerDto dealerDto) {
        logger.info("DealerDto > {} " + dealerDto)

```
final String procedureCall = "{call deleteDealer(?,?)}";


    logger.trace("procedure call funtion {}" + procedureCall);
    logger.info("get dealerCode"+dealerDto.getDealerCode());
    Connection connection = null;

    try {

        // Get Connection instance from dataSource
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        CallableStatement callableSt = connection.prepareCall(procedureCall);

        callableSt.setString("dealerCode", dealerDto.getDealerCode());
        logger.info("dealerCode"+dealerDto.getDealerCode());
        callableSt.registerOutParameter("result", Types.INTEGER);

        // Call Stored Procedure
        callableSt.executeUpdate();

        if( callableSt.getInt("result")==1){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        return false;
    }

}
```